# How can adding a JavaScript background effect disable controls in my element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

First of all, here's a link to a page I'm working on, so you can see what I mean for yourself:
http://37.60.224.20/~mdg17761/mirzarasic.com/about-me/

And, here's a link to the effect in the background:
https://github.com/jnicol/particleground

If you go to the page, you'll notice you can't scroll the section in the middle. The website link also isn't clickable and you can't select any of the text.

I'm using Wordpress with the Divi theme to build the website, as well.
I've added the code which creates the background in a Code Module and, it looks like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    particleground(document.getElementById("particleground"), {
        dotColor: &#039;#ffffff&#039;,
        lineColor: &#039;#blue&#039;,
        particleRadius: 0
    });
    var intro = document.getElementById(&#039;intro&#039;);
    intro.style.marginTop = -intro.offsetHeight / 2 + &#039;px&#039;;
}, false);
</script>

<style>
#particleground {
    position: relative;
}
#particleground canvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 996;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
</style>
```

Removing the Code Module makes the entire section work again. I've been looking through the source of the plugin, but, I simply don't have enough experience with JavaScript and can't figure out what might be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the particle canvas in the background?

You'll need to change the z-index of your "particle ground", as it's rendering on top of your content area. I'd consider adjusting where you put the code for the particle ground (either higher in the DOM for a naturally lower `z-index`, or at the bottom closer to the `</body>` tag and setting the `z-index` to `0` giving it a structurally lower presence while still needing to lower the `z-index`.

```
#particleground {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

(Note, with this you can remove the `z-index` from your `#particleground canvas` selector.

If you don't want the center section to be white (which the above code will do), you can set the background of it to transparent to let the canvas show through it:

```
.et_pb_section_1 {
    background: transparent;
 }
```

If you really want the particles "on top" for some reason, while I *strongly* recommend against it, you can add `pointer-events: none;` to `#particleground` - read more [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Comment: I would apply the `z-index` property to the parent, though (#particleground).